# How to force blank or black screen under windows

Tags: windows, directx

Is there a way under Windows to force the screen to be blank or black while exiting the current game process and launching a new game process?

Basically, I have multiple PCs running the same game at the same moment in time.  I want to be able to switch to a different game on all computers without ever showing the Windows interface.  I've written a C# application that allows me to exit the current game process on every PC and launch the new game process on all PCs but I'm not sure how to blank the screen while this happens so the Windows interface is never shown.  The PCs are connected to projectors and I could attempt to automate sending IR commands to blank/unblank the projectors while switching games but this feels clunky.

Comment: Why not just set up black wallpaper and kill Explorer.exe?

Comment: Clever, I guess I wasn't aware you could kill Explorer.exe -- I'll try it though.

Comment: Yeap, desktop and start menu is just a window of Explorer, kill it and you end up with just wallpaper (or solid background in older systems if I remember correctly)